# Can't pass querystring using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, query-string

Using the code below will not add the query string 'section' to the link. The url adds just fine but what am i doing wrong with the query string?

```
@Html.Hidden("Url", Request.RawUrl)
@Html.Hidden("Query", sectionGroup.Term)

<a href="#" id="ajaxLink">@sectionGroup.Term</a>

<script>
  $("#ajaxLink").click(function () {     
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $("#Url").val(),
      data: { section : $("#Query").val() }
    }).done(function() {

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You got confused between querystring and POST data. First decide what you want to pass, those are two different things.

Comment: I want to add a querystring to the url like: www.url.com/?section=value

Comment: So change to `url: $("#Url").val() + "?section=value",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between `GET` and `POST`.

Take a look at this: [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

The code working is here: http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/WtQsF/

**javascript**

```
$('#ajaxLink').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('href', '?section=' + $('#query').val());
});
```

The code takes the existing `href` and replace it with the desired. Maybe you may need to adapt a little bit ...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the type: "POST" to type: "GET" for the query string to be passed.